# How do I setup an ssh key system without interaction?

Tags: ssh

I need to be able to setup a `ssh` key system without interaction. I don't care if packages need to be installed or passwords in clear text.

How can I make a system that sets up a `ssh` key system, allowing machine A to `ssh` into the machine B and vice versa using ssh keys, without interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the plain code (**copying and pasting WILL NOT WORK!!! Change things like `my-username` and `my-ip`**). Run on both hosts:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y install sshpass
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sshpass -p 'my_password' ssh-copy-id my_username@my_host_2
```

Replace `my_host_2` with `my_host_1` on machine 2.

Explanation:

The first line, `#!/bin/bash` is called a shebang. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for more information.

The second line installs `sshpass` without interaction.

The third line uses `ssh-keygen` to create a key. `-q` means quiet; it dosen't ask as much. `-N ""` means no password and `-f` means to save it in the default location.

The last line copies the actual key using `ssh-copy-id` and `sshpass`. You cannot `echo` the password through `stdin`, so we use `sshpass` which is the closest equivalent. `-p` is the password to use. The argument to `ssh-copy-id` is the username and host to copy the key to.